# Identifying changed fields in java POJO class

Tags: java, dao, getter-setter, pojo

I got a java POJO class with 10+ members. There is a REST API call to save/update data to the database table.

For update call, after verifying POJO class memebers which are not null then saving only those fields to the table.

I want to log which fields are being updated. But don't want to add log statements in all the 10+ null check blocks.

```
                if (POJOclass.getfield1() != null) {
                    daoObject.setfield1(POJOclass.getfield1());
                }

                if (POJOclass.getfield2() != null) {
                    daoObject.setfield2(POJOclass.getfield2());
                }
```

Any suggestions for implementation is really appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at a mapper like mapstruct and compare the object you got via the api and the object that represents the current database state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand correctly you can have custom method that checks non null fields and non empty fields and log them (you can customize how ever you want)

```
public static void StringNullOREmpty(Pojo po) {

    Field[] f = po.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
    Arrays.stream(f).forEach(i->{;
    i.setAccessible(true); // need to be true to access private fields of pojo class
       try {
           if(i.get(po)!=null && !i.get(po).toString().trim().isEmpty()) {
               System.out.println(i.get(po).toString()+" filed name "+i.getName());
           }
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException | IllegalAccessException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    });

}
```

Example filed class:

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Setter
@Getter
class Pojo{
    private String field1 = "hey";

    private String field2 = "hello";

    private Integer fiedl3=10;

    private String field5;

    private String field6 = ""; 

 }
```

**Output**

```
hey filed name field1
hello filed name field2
10 filed name fiedl3
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me. But one more thing is, i've another Pojo class inside Pojo. Something like Address object(Properties: 1st line,2nd line, zip etc) inside Student object.